# $(x/a)^2+(y/b)^2=1, y\ge0$. the region bounded by the curve and the line y=0 is revolved about x-axis.

Tags: integration

The solid will become a sphere when $a=b$. In how many seconds will the solid become a sphere, assuming the rate of change of $a$ and the volume $V$ of the solid both remain constant?

I have integrated and have got that the volume  $ V=\frac{4}{3} \pi ab^2$. But how should I find time?

Answer (score 0):

$$ V = \frac43 \pi a b^2$$

By logarithmic differentiation

$$\frac{dV/dt}{V}=\frac{da/dt}{a}+2\frac{db/dt}{b}$$

Only one quantity is unknown, an approximate estimate $ da = a-b ,\, db=0 $ can be made. You can estimate $t$  further.